# Showing warning for unused method parameter?

Tags: eclipse, parameters, warnings

I am using Eclipse v3.5.

In previous Eclipse versions i remember if i have defined a method with a parameter and didn't use it internally a warning appears, like this :

```
public void myMethod( int x ) {
  // Didn't use x here so a warning appears at the x parameter.
}
```

But in v3.5 i do not see this warning. How can i enable it in Eclipse ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

See

> Window / Preferences / Java / Compiler
>   / ErrorsWarnings / Unnecessary Code /
>   Value of parameter is not used

In old versions (before Eclipse Juno?) the setting was called *"Parameter is never read"*.

Note:

If there is a valid reason for not using a parameter (e.g. it is used via reflection), you can suppress the warning by annotating the method with

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
```